# How to define a template function for a reference parameter and the same function for a pointer parameter

Tags: c++, templates, boost, stl

I want to define a templated functor for name comparison, that takes references as well
as pointers. I want to use this for a normal find_if on a container of elements as well as for a container of pointers (unfortunately ptr_vector or the like is not an option).

The best solution I have found so far is the following.

```
template <typename U>
class by_name{
  public:
    by_name(U const& pName):mName(pName) {}

    template <class T>
    typename boost::disable_if_c<boost::is_pointer<T>::value, bool>::type
    operator()(T const& pX){ return pX.getName()== mName;}

    template <class T>
    typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_pointer<T>::value, bool>::type
    operator()(T pX){ return pX->getName()== mName;}

private:
    U mName;
};
```

This looks quite ugly and very hard to understand for people not knowing enable_if.
Is there an easier way to write such a functor taking pointer and reference alike?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be as simple as:

```
template <class T>
bool operator()(T const& rX) const { return rX.getName() == mName; }

template <class T>
bool operator()(T* const pX) const { return pX->getName() == mName; }
```

Comment: Presumably the pointer version is the same `const`-wise, so we'd want `T const*` as a parameter. Even better, we could have its implementation in terms of the reference version: `return (*this)(*pX);`.

Answer (score 1):

Do the classes that implement getName member functions return anything else than std::string? If not, you can get rid of one template parameter.

This is how I would have implemented the functor:

```
class by_name
{
  public:
    by_name(const std::string& name) :
      Name(name) {}

    template <class T>
    bool operator()(T const& pX) const
    {
      return pX.getName() == Name;
    }

    template <class T>
    bool operator()(T* pX) const
    {
      if (!pX)  // how do you handle a null ptr?
        return false;
      (*this)(*pX); // @Luc Danton 
    }

  private:
    std::string Name;
};
```

If the pointer version is implemented as

```
bool operator(T const* pX) const {}
```

gcc for some reason choose to instantiate

```
bool operator(T const& pX) const with [T = A*]
```

The functor has been compiled and tested with gcc 4.6.1.

Comment: Good Idea but I have QString as well to deal with thus two string types in the system